# How to edit a text file with shell script (split, replace, concatenate..)

Tags: shell, text, replace, split, concatenation

I am trying to make a script for text editing. My text file have data like

```
3c26 d3ac 27d4 c03f 5dc4 5242 1d96 bbbf
4b7c 84bf 51fb c73f f784 7a8e bee9 c6bf
32df aafb bcf9 6ebf 099b de28 5714 bcbf
7ada f876 320a c9bf 9afc 7ea2 f4b4 c93f
```

I want to concatenate each 4 blocks of numbers after that write each one in a line proceeded by `0x` and finishes by `,`

I want the text to look like this

```
0x3c26d3ac27d4c03f,
0x5dc452421d96bbbf,
0x4b7c84bf51fbc73f,
0xf7847a8ebee9c6bf,
0x32dfaafbbcf96ebf,
0x099bde285714bcbf,
0x7adaf876320ac9bf, 
0x9afc7ea2f4b4c93f,
```

Comment: Show us the code you wrote so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple **Sed** and **Awk** will work here

```
#cat your_file_name|sed '/^ *$/d' |awk '{print ("0x"$1$2$3$4",""\n""0x"$5$6$7$7",")}'
0x3c26d3ac27d4c03f,
0x5dc452421d961d96,
0x4b7c84bf51fbc73f,
0xf7847a8ebee9bee9,
0x32dfaafbbcf96ebf,
0x099bde2857145714,
0x7adaf876320ac9bf,
0x9afc7ea2f4b4f4b4,
```

This is the simplest way to implement, Please take refernce and optimize with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oE '[a-z0-9]{4}' input.txt | awk '{ l = l $0; if ((NR % 4) == 0){ print "0x" l ","; l = "" }}'

0x3c26d3ac27d4c03f,
0x5dc452421d96bbbf,
0x4b7c84bf51fbc73f,
0xf7847a8ebee9c6bf,
0x32dfaafbbcf96ebf,
0x099bde285714bcbf,
0x7adaf876320ac9bf,
0x9afc7ea2f4b4c93f,
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but i need to run this command on 51750 lines, which it does not work in terminal, so if it is possible to create another file as output where the values are saved there, or edited in the same file

Comment: save the ouput in new file

Answer (score -1):

Command

```
sed -e 's/.\{20\}/&\n/g' filename | sed 's/ //g;s/.*/0x&,/g'
```

Output

```
0x3c26d3ac27d4c03f,
0x5dc452421d961d96,
0x4b7c84bf51fbc73f,
0xf7847a8ebee9bee9,
0x32dfaafbbcf96ebf,
0x099bde2857145714,
0x7adaf876320ac9bf,
0x9afc7ea2f4b4f4b4,
```